# Console not appearing in rails action view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, raise

For some reason the console at the bottom of my action view page has disappeared so i cant debug anything. This normally appears automatically and have never had to make it appear before. Anyone know why/how to fix this? thanks[image]

Comment: i had the exact same issue! My problem appeared only during the use of `ngrok`, which is a gem that forwards your localhost server to a publically accessible link. I switched back to localhost:3000 and everything was working as always. Maybe that helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This gem is added by-default in your Gemfile for the development environment.

```
gem 'web_console'  #Responsible for accessing an IRB console on exception pages.
```

For example:

```
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end
```

Please check it is present or not. If not then added to it in the Gemfile.

Or may be you run the server in the production mode as this gem is set by-default for the development environment in the Gemfile.

Comment: the gem is present. i'm not having an issue with the error page showing. Im having an issue with the console showing at the bottom of the error page

Comment: I know. It is also responsible for console that is showing at the bottom of the error page.

Comment: try to upgrade the web_console: gem 'web-console', '3.6.2'  ....see link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138551/rails-web-console-not-showing-on-run-time-error-page

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/rails/web-console

You are able to add `<%= console %>` in your view, or simply `console` in your controller's action. You can also use Byebug to debug with the computer's terminal

Answer (score 0):

not a very good answer. But it seems like the console reset itself as the the input field suddenly came back. maybe resets every month??